# Text file seen as a list of char, not as a list of str

Tags: python, string, list, element

I am new to *Python* - only used *PERL* before. I have a problem dealing with text files. I open a file and try to iterate through the lines but it appears that Python sees the file not as a list of strings (lines) but as a list of characters (individual letters):

```
def open_dat_xml(file_name):

    file_handle = open(file_name)

    file_content = file_handle.read()

    file_handle.close()

    return file_content

list_of_lines = open_dat_xml('F003603_short.dat.xml')

for i in list_of_lines:
    print i
```

The file I am opening is XML but I have seen the same behavior with plain text files.

**How to force Python to to see the file as a list of strings?**

Comment: I just want to note that the problem is caused by the fact that `file_handle.read()` returns the entire contents of the file as a string. So your variable `list_of_lines` is a string, not a list at all. And iterating over a string iterates over its characters.

Comment: As a side note, in Python, characters are just strings of length 1, and strings are sequences of characters, so… you actually already _have_ a sequence of strings, just not the one you want. (EDIT: @RemcoGerlich just said most of this 1 second before me… but there's still a but of extra info here I think.)

Answer (score 3):

A file is *already* an iterable of lines. Just use it as such:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        do_stuff(line)
```

Do not call `readlines()`. Really, [there's no reason to *ever* do so](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html).

If you need to iterate the lines multiple times, keep them around after the file is closed, etc., it's simpler and clearer to do the same thing you do any other time you need a list from some possibly-not-a-list-iterable and call `list`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    return list(f)
```

But usually, you don't need any of that, so just use the file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `file_content = file_handle.readlines()` isntead of `.read()`.

Also, try using context manager instead of `open/close`:

```
def open_dat_xml(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file_handle:
        file_content = file_handle.read()
    return file_content
```

or even shorter:

```
def open_dat_xml(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file_handle:
        return file_handle.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def open_dat_xml(file_name):
    # The with statement closes the file as well
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return f.readlines()
```